# LG l90 led light

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop, camera-flash, super-amoled, lg-optimus-l90

The L.E.D. on a LG l90 Android I recently purchased does not light up. I have tried going to setting, but can find no toggle switch to activate the L.E.D.  What should i do?

Comment: Which LED are you talking about? The camera flash/flashlight? The screen backlight? The notification light? Please specify.

Comment: Assuming that you are referring to the camera flash/flashlight, there should be a widget toggle you can place on your home screen. It will most likely be called "flashlight" or "torch". If not, there are plenty of third-party apps available on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=flashlight%20widget), usually requiring some trial-and-error to find one that works with your particular device.

Comment: Thanks & i am indeed refering to the  flashlight/camera flash. I have placed the widget & tried various apps but have had no luck.

Comment: Does the LED function correctly when used as the camera flash?

Comment: No the LED does not function in any capacity that I have discovered

Comment: This is starting to sound like a warranty issue with a defective product and not necessarily a software problem. You said the device was recently purchased. I think it's time to get the seller involved or perhaps [contact LG](http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGD415RD).